# Set of combinations of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of independent vectors {${u, v}$} and I need to determine if the set of vectors {$u - v, v, 4v$} is also linearly independent. I originally saw the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985509/linear-dependence-of-set-of-linear-combinations-of-linearly-independent-vectors?rq=1) which seems to be exactly what I need to do, however I'm slightly confused about the combination of $v$ and $4v$. It seems that those two are already linearly dependent so it seems that I could simply leave out the $4v$ and show that $u-v$ and $v$ are linearly independent:

$$a*(u - v) + b(v) = 0\\ 
(a) * u + (-a + b) * v = 0
$$

which leads  to

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

from which I can say that the two vectors are linearly independent, because there is no non-trivial solution. Is it possible to leave out the $4v$?

Comment: You are right: $\{u-v,v\}$ is a linearly independent set but $\{u-v,v,4v\}$ is not.

Comment: The subsystem $\{v,4v\}$ is linearly dependent, hence, the whole system is dependent as well.

Comment: No three vectors in a two dimensional system can be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just choose one of $v$ or $4v$ for the purposes of this question. As you remark, $v$ and $4v$ are linearly dependent because 
$$ 4v+(-4)v=0$$
while the coefficients of $4v$ and $v$ are nontrivial. For your original question of "is $\{u-v,v,4v\}$ linearly independent?" this is sufficient. Take 
$$ 0(u-v)+4v+(-4)v=0.$$
If you wish to proceed anyway to learn about $\{u-v,v\}$, then from here you can just row reduce the unaugmented system
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-1&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
to find the dimension of $\text{span}(u-v,v)$. It's basically true by inspection that the dimension of this span is $2$, so that they are indeed linearly independent.